Method References in VsCode flutter
Is there a way or plugin to display the references on top of a method declarations in VsCode with Dart code? Something similar to Visual Studio reference display?

As far as I remember there is a similar thing in the official Dart Code or Dart extension, enable the editor.codeLens option

According to the official documentation of Visual Studio Code

Some languages like C# support inline reference information, that is
updated live. This allows you to quickly analyze the impact of your
edit or the popularity of your specific method or property throughout
your project:



Tip: Directly invoke the Peek References action by clicking on these
annotations.
Tip: Reference information shown in CodeLens can be turned on or off
through the editor.codeLens setting.

It clearly described that Some languages like C# support inline reference information, that is updated live.
So it suggests using Peek features of VS Code instead (if Dart programming language does not yet support how C# behaves in showing references of a method).
Here's how:

When you execute a Go to References search (via Shift+F12), or a
Peek Definition (via Alt+F12), we embed the result inline

Here's the source for more info regarding that context: Code Navigation
Or if you need to add it specifically to a particular language; under the Language specific editor settings
In addition, if you still want to achieve a similar behavior of it.
Then try this if it matches your use case:
Update
Methods inside a single class
/// [test2] // manual setting of method reference
void test1() { //method 1
  debugPrint('this is a test 1');
  test2();
}

/// [test3] // manual setting of method reference
void test2() { //method 2
  debugPrint('this is a test 2');
  test3();
}

/// [test1],[test2] // manual setting of method references
void test3() { //method 3
  debugPrint('this is a test 3');
  test1();
  test2();
}

Method from different classes
class ClassA {
  void methodA1() {
    debugPrint("Test ClassA's method 1");
  }
}

class ClassC {
  void methodA1() { // I've just decided to mimic the ClassA's methodA1
    debugPrint("Test ClassC's method 1");
  }
}

class ClassB {
  /// [ClassA.methodA1]
  void methodB1() {
    ClassA().methodA1();
  }
}

Kindly read this for more details: Documentation comment references
